# How to restore the GUI at login on Ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, xfce, plymouth

Because my Xubuntu reported plymouth crashing each time I logged in, I used `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove everthing related to `plymouth`.

Now I can only login with terminal. And I have to use `startx` to start an Xfce desktop.

So how can I restore the GUI login?

And I don't want some *magical recipe* but want to know how exactly plymouth, terminal, Xfce desktop, startx work together. Where should I start?

Comment: Please next time don't remove any thing simply because its not acting well at that moment. Try: `sudo apt install plymouth-x11` , `plymouth` seems to be giving so much trouble these days

Comment: A hungry man should not turn his nose up at food cooked with a *magic recipe* nor should you or I refuse to enter a one line command to fix our computers just because we don't comprehend every punctuation meaning.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thx. I wish I could let it go.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `sudo apt install` to re-install the packages you removed earlier. Propably `sudo install Plymouth` will do it.

There are a nice article about plynouth here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth